# Angularjs How submit a form after upload image

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image-uploading, angular-controller

I'm trying to **submit** a `form` from my **controller** when I **upload** the image.

I'm not sure how I can do that.

Any help will be appreciated!

```js
(function(angular) {
      'use strict';
      angular.module('includeExample', ['ngAnimate'])
        .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$q',
          function($scope, $q) {
                $scope.uploadStart = function(){
                  $("#test").html("upload started");
                };
          

          }
        ]);
    })(window.angular);
```

```css
.image-upload > input
{
  display: none;
}

.image-upload img
{
  width: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://institucional.portoseguro.com.br/visual/v.0.2/css/ps-lib.full-min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div ng-app="includeExample" ng-controller="ExampleController" class="box-image ps-mod1 ps-lg-mod1">
    <div class="image-grouped image-upload"  >
  <form ng-submit="uploadStart()">
   <label for="file-input" >
            <span class="ps-ico ps-ico-xm ps-glyph ps-ico-camera"></span>
   </label>
  
      <input id="file-input" type="file"/>
   <style type="text/css">
    .image-upload input
    {
        display: none;
    }
    .image-upload label 
    {      
        cursor: pointer;
    }
   </style>
   <img alt="Brand" src="https://ec.europa.eu/digital-agenda/sites/digital-agenda/files/styles/square_thumbnail/public/default_images/user_default.png?itok=m56b0Aym">
  </div>
 </div>
    <label id="test"></label>
```

Comment: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Comment: You have a random </a> in your form.

Comment: @ErwinKraan I can't install any other third party libs in this project. I wondering if I can manipulate pure angular and js.

Comment: Ok, that is a bummer. I know it's possible with or normal jquery. If you want to do it $http it's possible but if I'm correct your need to transform the request. There was a good article about that but I can't find it anymore :( sorry that I can't help you further